# Graphhopper API vs Graphhopper app

Tags: graphhopper

I'm using Graphhopper [core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphhopper/graphhopper-core/0.9.0) library to compute distance and best path between 2 points, i read about Graphhopper Routing [API](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/routing/) and as explained [here](https://www.graphhopper.com/pricing/), API has a pricing scheme , so my question is what actually will the add-on that's provided by API that's not exist inside APP 
that worth paying ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure if this belongs to SO, but here you have a rough guidance.

Advantages of the [GraphHopper Routing API](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/routing/):

- hosted and fault tolerant service with support
- highly optimized configuration
- frequent software updates (runs cutting edge & tested versions)
- frequent data updates (usually daily, guaranteed weekly)
- no need to buy servers with >50GB RAM that are usually required to run a world wide setup
- integrates easily with jsprit via `optimize=true` or [the Route Optimization API](https://graphhopper.com/api/1/docs/route-optimization/)
- with truck profiles out of the box
- improved heuristics to calculate ETAs with OSM data (we work on making this open source hopefully soon)
- optionally instead OSM data with TomTom data and [time dependent historic traffic data](https://www.graphhopper.com/blog/2017/11/06/time-dependent-optimization/)
- other APIs like the Matrix API, see the comparison table [here](https://www.graphhopper.com/open-source/) and reasoning about closed vs. open source [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/131)

Advantages of [the open source project](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper) (Java knowledge required):

- highly customizable to e.g. tune country or use case specific rules. (this is now also available for the GraphHopper Routing API via a dedicated setup)
- write any vehicle profile
- [active community](https://discuss.graphhopper.com/)
- import of any data source (can read osm xml, pbf, shp, custom) for the road network or for elevation data
- runs offline e.g. on Android or iOS
- currently public transit routing is only available in the open source project
- find nearest point API (can be simulated with a routing request where start=end)
- can do indoor navigation in theory, in practice have a look [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/646)